# How to partition by neighboring values?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have data that looks like this:

```
dt         val
2020-01-01 A
2020-01-02 A
2020-01-03 B
2020-01-04 B
2020-01-05 B
2020-01-06 C
2020-01-07 C
2020-01-08 B
2020-01-09 A
2020-01-10 A
2020-01-11 A
```

Is it possible to define a partition by neighboring values of `val` to define:

```
dt         val block_start_dt block_end_dt prev_block_end_dt next_block_start_dt
2020-01-01 A   2020-01-01     2020-01-02   null              2020-01-03
2020-01-02 A   2020-01-01     2020-01-02   null              2020-01-03
2020-01-03 B   2020-01-03     2020-01-05   2020-01-02        2020-01-06
2020-01-04 B   2020-01-03     2020-01-05   2020-01-02        2020-01-06
2020-01-05 B   2020-01-03     2020-01-05   2020-01-02        2020-01-06
2020-01-06 C   2020-01-06     2020-01-07   2020-01-05        2020-01-08
2020-01-07 C   2020-01-06     2020-01-07   2020-01-05        2020-01-08
2020-01-08 B   2020-01-08     2020-01-08   2020-01-07        2020-01-09
2020-01-09 A   2020-01-09     2020-01-11   2020-01-08        null
2020-01-10 A   2020-01-09     2020-01-11   2020-01-08        null
2020-01-11 A   2020-01-09     2020-01-11   2020-01-08        null
```

The only way that I can think of is use window functions thrice in subqueries, but I was wondering if there was any way to do it without reading in the data thrice.

Comment: How would I know if my solution were different from yours? Hint: edit your question and include the query (or queries) that you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a gaps and islands approach, but having first used LAG() and LEAD() to find the dates for the preceding and succeeding groups...

```
WITH
  pre_and_post AS
(
  SELECT
    data.*,
    CASE WHEN  LAG(val) OVER (ORDER BY dt) <> val THEN  LAG(dt) OVER (ORDER BY dt) END   AS prev_end,
    CASE WHEN LEAD(val) OVER (ORDER BY dt) <> val THEN LEAD(dt) OVER (ORDER BY dt) END   AS next_start
  FROM
    data
),
  gaps_and_islands AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (                 ORDER BY dt)
    -
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY val ORDER BY dt)   AS val_group_id
  FROM
    pre_and_post
)
SELECT
  dt,
  val,
  MIN(dt        ) OVER (PARTITION BY val, val_group_id)   AS val_group_start,
  MAX(dt        ) OVER (PARTITION BY val, val_group_id)   AS val_group_end,
  MAX(prev_end  ) OVER (PARTITION BY val, val_group_id)   AS prev_val_group_end,
  MAX(next_start) OVER (PARTITION BY val, val_group_id)   AS next_val_group_start
FROM
  gaps_and_islands
ORDER BY
  dt
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=799ca51c518e4014e5156ff369043313

Comment: oh, this is clever.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim - Look at the fiddle example.  Each group only has one non-NULL value in `prev_end` and `next_start`.  As such `MAX(prev_end)` and `MIN(prev_end)` will give the same result.

Answer (score 1):

it can also be done with way too many nested window functions, but zero joins like:

```
WITH data AS (
select * from values
  ('2020-01-01', 'A'),
  ('2020-01-02', 'A'),
  ('2020-01-03', 'B'),
  ('2020-01-04', 'B'),
  ('2020-01-05', 'B'),
  ('2020-01-06', 'C'),
  ('2020-01-07', 'C'),
  ('2020-01-08', 'B'),
  ('2020-01-09', 'A'),
  ('2020-01-10', 'A'),
  ('2020-01-11', 'A')
   v(dt,val)
)
SELECT 
    dt
    ,val
    ,block_start_dt
    ,block_end_dt
    ,COALESCE(lag_block_end_dt_a,lag(lag_block_end_dt_a) ignore nulls over(order by dt)) as pre_block_end_dt
    ,COALESCE(lead_block_start_dt_a,lead(lead_block_start_dt_a) ignore nulls over(order by dt)) as next_block_start_dt
FROM (
    SELECT b.*
        ,lag(block_end_dt) over (order by dt) as lag_block_end_dt
        ,iff(lag_block_end_dt=block_end_dt, null, lag_block_end_dt) as lag_block_end_dt_a
        ,lead(block_start_dt) over (order by dt) as lead_block_start_dt
        ,iff(lead_block_start_dt=block_start_dt, null, lead_block_start_dt) as lead_block_start_dt_a
    FROM (
        SELECT a.*
            ,first_value(dt) over (partition by val, block order by dt) as block_start_dt
            ,last_value(dt) over (partition by val, block order by dt) as block_end_dt
        FROM (
            SELECT dt
                ,val
                ,row_number() over(order by dt) - row_number() over(partition by val order by dt) as block
            FROM data
        ) a
    ) b
) c
order by dt;
```

gives:

```
DT          VAL BLOCK_START_DT  BLOCK_END_DT    PRE_BLOCK_END_DT    NEXT_BLOCK_START_DT
2020-01-01  A   2020-01-01      2020-01-02  null        2020-01-03
2020-01-02  A   2020-01-01      2020-01-02  null        2020-01-03
2020-01-03  B   2020-01-03      2020-01-05  2020-01-02  2020-01-06
2020-01-04  B   2020-01-03      2020-01-05  2020-01-02  2020-01-06
2020-01-05  B   2020-01-03      2020-01-05  2020-01-02  2020-01-06
2020-01-06  C   2020-01-06      2020-01-07  2020-01-05  2020-01-08
2020-01-07  C   2020-01-06      2020-01-07  2020-01-05  2020-01-08
2020-01-08  B   2020-01-08      2020-01-08  2020-01-07  2020-01-09
2020-01-09  A   2020-01-09      2020-01-11  2020-01-08  null
2020-01-10  A   2020-01-09      2020-01-11  2020-01-08  null
2020-01-11  A   2020-01-09      2020-01-11  2020-01-08  null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can basically do what you want by aggregating the rows as a gaps-and-islands problem.  The basic idea is the difference of row numbers, but you want additional information about adjacent blocks as well:

```
select val, min(dt) as block_start_dt, max(dt) as block_end_dt,
       lag(min(dt)) over (order by min(dt)) as prev_block_start_dt,
       lag(max(dt)) over (order by min(dt)) as prev_block_end_dt,
       lead(min(dt)) over (order by min(dt)) as next_block_start_dt,
       lead(max(dt)) over (order by min(dt)) as next_block_end_dt
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by dt) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by val order by dt) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by val, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

That might be sufficient for your purposes.  But . . . you can join this back to your data to get detail on each row:

```
select t.*, x.*
from t join
     (select val, min(dt) as block_start_dt, max(dt) as block_end_dt,
             lag(min(dt)) over (order by min(dt)) as prev_block_start_dt,
             lag(max(dt)) over (order by min(dt)) as prev_block_end_dt,
             lead(min(dt)) over (order by min(dt)) as next_block_start_dt,
             lead(max(dt)) over (order by min(dt)) as next_block_end_dt
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (order by dt) as seqnum,
                   row_number() over (partition by val order by dt) as seqnum_2
            from t
           ) t
      group by val, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
     ) x
     on t.val = x.val and
        t.dt between x.block_start_dt and x.block_end_dt;
```